# best options for data when travelling USA and Canada

Tags: roaming

So we  are from New Zealand and are planning a 3 month campervan trip across Canada and back via USA thru Maine, Vermont South Dakota etc

What would be best options for having data so we can search for campsites and things to do in each state etc

Comment: How much data do you need per month? Be more specific.

Comment: When you find out do please come back & tell me :-) - I'm in Auckland.  I surprised at the question being put on hold. I'll ask your question in a more   information friendly forum and see what people say.